# How to permute an Excel column of values?

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say we have a column of cells value in column A and need to permute this column randomly into column B as in this [simple sample](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2013/simple%20permute.xlsm).

How can I do that?

I tried with my VBA code but it seems not working. I guess my below command got some issues that I don't know what they are - I need to transfer back the array of values in variable varValues back into the cells

```
Range("B1:B10").Cells.Value = varValues
```

Comment: You can't run your function to do both at the same time: change any value to different cell (which is forbidden for functions) other than destination cell and return value like 'Done' at the same time. You need to choose which direction you want to go.

Comment: I see. I'll choose to run the method as a macro

Comment: so, is your problem solved (I think it is now) or you need any further help?

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code from the sample file and it works without any editing.  Is that the code you are having trouble with?  If not please post the actual code you have trouble with.

If you're looking to replace the original then simply have the same range as the code in the file e.g.

```
Set rng = Range("A1:A10")
...
Range("A1:A10").Cells.Value2 = varValues
```

Comment: Indeed I've just learned the syntax to assign array to cells and noted here http://namgivu.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/how-to-assign-vba-array-of-values-to-a-range-of-cells/

Answer (score 0):

My issues are

- Running methods that change the cells' values must be done via macro
- Assigning `variant` data type to range's cells value is done via [correct syntax](http://namgivu.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/how-to-assign-vba-array-of-values-to-a-range-of-cells/) e.g, `Range("a1:a10") = xdata`